# Can't subdivide my human face model

Tags: subdivision-surface

I model my face Via KeeenTool add on and want to use a sculpt brush for skin texturing , but when I subdivide it it looks unsmooth// like everything cover with squares!

I've tried to subdivide it with normal right click in *Edit Mode*, with the *Subdivision Subsurface* modifier, and also with the Multiresolution and all do the same.

[image]